# Function abstraction & promise function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to abstract the function below so I can reuse easily.  Function basically runs a given function that returns a promise max 5 times or until the promise is resolved.
DataFn is giving me particularly a hard time.  It returns a promise but when the run function is executed the second time after a first fail, it doesn't try to connect to the server again.  If I hard code the function name it works, but as a passed parameter only works in the beginning.

```
var persistentPromise = (function() {
    var maxRetries = 0;
    return function run(dataFn, messageObject) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        dataFn.$promise.then(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            },
            function (response) {
                if(response == 503) {
                    if(++maxRetries < 6) {
                        messageService.emit(messageObject.warning);
                        $timeout(function () {
                            run(dataFn, messageObject);
                        }, 10000);
                    } else {
                        messageService.emit(messageObject.end);
                        deferred.reject(messageObject.na);
                    }
                }
            });
        deferred.promise.then(function (response) {
            $scope.transactionData = {
                transactions: kpiService.totalArrayAmountWithRange(response.rows, 2, 0, response.rows.length / 2) + kpiService.totalArrayAmountWithRange(response.rows, 2, response.rows.length / 2 + 1, response.rows.length)
            };
            usSpinnerService.stop('loaderspin');
        }, function(response) {
            usSpinnerService.stop('loaderspin');
            $scope.transactionData = {
                transactions: response.na.msg
            };
        });
    };
})();

/* calling the function */
persistentPromise(promiseFunction, someMessageObject);
```

Comment: It's hard to follow. In particular, what is `dataFn`? It's not called and the only aspect of it that's used is its `.$promise` property.

Comment: it's a function with an ajax call that returns a promise

Comment: So where is it called?

Comment: I added another line on how to call the function, at the bottom.

Comment: See Benjamin's answer. He explains all and provides a neat solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can completely decompose that code into reusable parts. Remember that promises use `return` statements and abstract the very base of an asynchronous value.

**Promises represent the value and not an operation** - your dataFn is not a function but a result of a function you're just waiting `n` times 10 seconds and not actually performing any more calls.

Let's start with a `retry`:

```
// fn - arbitrary function that returns a promise, in your case this is what
// generates dataFn and __not__ dataFn itself. n - the number of retries
function retry(fn, n){ 
    var reasons = []; // to keep rejection reasons
    return $q.when().then(function retry(){ // start the chain
        return fn(). // call the function
               catch(function(err){ // if it failed
                   reasons.push(err); // accumulate reasons for failure of fn()
                   if(n-- <= 0) return $q.reject(reasons); // no more retries
                   return retry(); // recursive call, note the return
               });
    });
}
```

Now you can retry any promise returning function any number of times, that's a decomposable bit.

Let's now look at your code again. There is a lot of complection by including the `$scope` and the uiSpinner in the function. Let's look at that spinner.

```
function spinUntil(fn){
    uiSpinnerService.start("loaderspin"); // start spinning, here and not outside
    return fn().finally(function(){ // after FN resolves
        uiSpinnerService.stop("loaderspin");
    });
}
```

which would let your whole code look something like:

```
spinUntil(function(){
    return retry(promiseReturningFunction, 5);
}).then(function(data){ // retries performed, spinner done
    $scope.transactionData = data; // assign here, don't complect the scope and the fn.
    // spinner and retries already done, $scope is not a concern of retry or spinUntil
});
```

Comment: I am getting not a function errors with your retry(), also this function doesn't have a timer.

Comment: your function also immediately returns after one catch.  doesn't resolve gracefully.

Comment: @z.a. the function works as advertized - see http://jsfiddle.net/ecL9vq9o/ - change the count from 5 to 3 for instance to see it fail becasue there are not enough retries.

Comment: Here's an even shorter version on - http://jsfiddle.net/Lkg1vd6h/ but it doesn't aggregate rejections.

Comment: I guess the problem could be that I am using a service with $resource methods.  That's the function I am trying to pass in

Comment: @z.a., do you possibly need to pass a bound instance of your function using `.bind(...)`, to give it context and/or params?

Comment: I don't think so.  Also how can I test this function?  trying but no luck.

Comment: @z.a. I put links to JSFiddle proving that this works correctly _twice_ now and it has been verified by another user (Roamer). You can check my post linking to JSFiddle and see it for yourself. If it returns a $resource you probably want to pass it something like `function(){ return myResourceCallingFn(arg1,arg2).$promise }` as the parameter.

Comment: Thanks.  That helped for sure.  Any advice on how to unit test this.  I have another question if you wanna hunt it down :).

Comment: Since you now have decomposed primitives rather than a method that does everything you can test 'retry' and the 'showSpinner' methods in complete isolation from testing your $resource methods - the $timeout bit you don't need to test since Angulr already tests that.

Answer (score -3):

I came with this function, which works great even if the function returns a promise.  Return is also a promise so the result can be processed easily.

```
function (fn, params, n) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        (function retry() {
            return fn(params).$promise
                .then(function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (n <= 0) {
                        deferred.reject(response);
                        return;
                    }
                    n--;
                    $timeout(function () {
                        return retry();
                    }, 5000);
                });
        })();
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```